# Layer Preview OpenLayers not working: Scale = 1:NaN

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am taking the tutorial from this site:
http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-autocomplete/

After I published taxlots layer and went to Layer Preview - Openlayers, the map was blank and on the bottom of the box it showed 'Scale = 1 : NaN'. If I chose Preview as JPEG the map showed up fine. It seemed there's something to do with map bounding or reference system? I have doubled checked everything but didn't see anything wrong.

I followed the same procedure and published another layer in shapefile format and in a different coordinate system. It worked fine.

BTW I am using OpenGeo Suite 4.7 and JRE 7 on Windows 7.

Comment: I assume you followed the tutorial correctly?  If it's working fine with another layer in another projection, it definitely just sounds like a data issue if you did the steps correctly.

Comment: I think I followed the tutorial correctly. Tried it twice. I have also viewed the data in QGIS and it looked fine.

Comment: If I export KML from the Preview Layer page, the KML cannot be opened in google earth. It gave the following error: parse error at line1, column0: out of memory.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. I thought it may be a data issue, however, everything displays correctly in QGIS and Open Jump using several different select quarries. I've also repeated the same exercise using the GeoServer nyc_building example with the expected result. The only difference in the logs that I'm noticing is the GET request is calling a format of application/openlayers with the taxlot dataset and image/png with the nyc_building example.

Comment: If anyone comes across this problem, you can continue with the tutorial and the end results will display with the expected result at the end.

Comment: Same issue here; I wonder why this is.